# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin

If I run `gradle assembleDebug` from the command line, I am suddenly getting this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

If I grep for v4 I see two files inside my build folder.

```
Binary file build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.0-2ba5fdd60a6c3836b3104a863fe42897da1fa9d1.jar matches
Binary file build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-r7-227d905d79b23b20866531d4f700446c040a2ccb.jar matches
```

My gradle file includes only this support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0'
```

I am stumped as to how the r7 library is included somehow. I've run `gradle clean` and it always appears there when I rerun assembleDebug.

If I grep for r7 inside the build directory, I see it inside the file:

```
Binary file build/exploded-bundles/ComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4030.aar/classes.jar matches
```

If I don't include v13, then other things don't compile.

But doesn't v13 include v4 support library?

Is this an incompatibility between play services AAR bundle and the v13 library?

I grabbed the gradle file from gradleplease.appspot.com.

Removing play services does not fix it; same error.

My dependencies inside build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {


 // Google Play Services
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'

// Support Libraries
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
///compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0'
compile 'org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:2.1.5'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
compile 'com.madgag:markdownj-core:0.4.1'
compile 'com.wu-man:android-oauth-client:0.0.2'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.17.0-rc'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions, and It happened all of them didn't work. Than I just created a new project with the same name, and copied all the files from the old project. And It works great now. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had this issue with a component in support-v13. After much debugging and trying all the answers to no avail, I found out it was introduced when I tried integrating kotlin into the project which was an exsiting java project. I removed the kotlin standard library and other kotlin libraries and it was fine. Would still try to fix the problem with kotlin but for now, I gotta work. Any info would help too, really love kotlin.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Run **`gradle -q dependencies`** (or **`gradle -q :projectName:dependencies`**) to generate a dependency report. You should see where `r7` is coming from, such as:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4
|    +--- com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android:support-v4:r7
|    +--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.5.4
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
```

Then, use the `exclude` directive to block that dependency. In my case, it is coming from my CWAC-Camera library, and so I use:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

(where the second `compile` statement indicates what version you actually want)

That should clear matters up, as you will see if you run the dependency report again:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4
|    +--- com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0
|    \--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.5.4
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
```

Comment: Build was broken after I added one new `compile` statement.
`gradle -q dependencies` has given me nothing, but adding exlusion to compile statement has fixed the problem.

Comment: Is there a method for inspecting/excluding modules from .jar dependencies not available on Maven? `gradle dependencies` seems to not report dependencies added with `compile files('libs/example.jar')`

Comment: @dbro: I guess I don't understand your scenario. Are you saying that you have a JAR in `libs/` that is also being pulled in via some artifact?

Comment: Let's say I have two `libs/*.jar` dependencies with a module in common, neither is available as an artifact. Any way to perform a similar dependency inspection / class exclusion?

Comment: @dbro: Not that I am aware of, but, then again, I have not researched this point. IMHO, off the cuff, one or both of those JAR files feel mis-packaged, as the module in common should be factored out into its own JAR.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie how to run "gradle -q dependencies" I don't know how to find gradle.exe

Comment: @um.anusorn: Sorry, but I can't help you there, as I do not regularly use Windows.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. I just try to config build.gradle on every modules that needs libs and now I can run my project! ^^

Comment: I had to run the following for the dependencies to print out: ./gradlew -q :<rootdir>:dependencies

Comment: @um.anusom if you are using Android Studio just select the terminal in the lower left of the program

Comment: @CommonsWare i've tried to exclude the modules like you wrote, but I get `Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'exclude()'!` and can't find much about this error. Is this related to gradle settings ?

Comment: @Michael: It is possible it is related to your version of Gradle or the Gradle for Android plugin.

Comment: My main build.gradle file mentions `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'` but `gradle-wrapper.properties` has `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip` .

Comment: @CommonsWare : hello, I followed you, but can not solve the problem. [Could u check for me please?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264223/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-in-android-studio)

Comment: I just killed a couple of hours trying to fix this. As @dbro points out, a manually added library will *not* have its dependencies listed, but unfortunately this "exclude" command seems to be ignored as well. In the end I couldn't exclude `support-v4` from the manually added lib, and instead had to exclude it from all my other dependencies acquired from Maven Central.

Comment: @TedAvery: If by "manually added library" you mean "something I put in `libs/`", then there *are* no dependencies, from the standpoint of automated dependency management. This is why the Android tools team is steering everyone towards converting those into artifacts in some repository (e.g., local repository, team repository).

Comment: ./gradlew -q dependencies should have the same effect right? When I do this, I get a header saying "Root project" and one line "No configurations" below it. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. I'm running `gradlew -q dependencies` as you suggested bu the only output is 
`------------------------------------------------------------Root project
------------------------------------------------------------
No configurations`
am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: ./gradlew -q :projectName:dependencies worked for me

Comment: Quick tip for those exlucing a module from a module dependency: You have to turn your `compile project(':foo')` into `compile(project(':foo')) { exclude module: 'support-v4' }`. Note the parenthesis.

Comment: in whit console should I run `gradle -q dependencies` and where is it?

Comment: @xedo: "in whit console should I run gradle -q dependencies" -- I used a terminal window in Ubuntu. The answer will vary by your desktop OS. "and where is it?" -- I installed a local copy of Gradle from gradle.org.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did it (Windows) but doesn't recognizes 'gradle'

Comment: @xedo: Make sure it is in your PATH. You will fine the Gradle executable in the `bin/` directory of wherever you installed Gradle.

Comment: If you get 'No configurations' then you need to do './gradlew -q :app:dependencies'.  This is confusing since everyone is saying to use ':projectName:dependencies', However, it's the application directory, not the project name that needs to go there!

Comment: For eclipse here's the SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058378/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibili/23558000#23558000

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please assist me in finding out the duplicate dependency in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084767/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v7-util-threadutilmainthreadcallback)  question? I've tried almost every option but to no avail.

Answer (score 123):

I solved similar error by adding following piece of code to my **build.gradle** file inside the android block.

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me!  Is there any down sides of doing it this way?

Comment: @BarrieGalitzky I haven't ran into any issues so far

Comment: Thanks man, this worked perfectly to solve the issue! Anyway, I think that it has some side effects.. The assembleDebug task became 3 times slower!

Comment: dexOptions not found.

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution to the problem. Thx man!

Comment: Not worked for me!! After adding the module inside android package i got the same error which appeared previously...

Comment: After adding this, I got "Translation has been interrupted" error. Guess I've to give CommonsWare method a try.

Answer (score 36):

Since **A picture is worth a thousand words**

To make it easier and faster to get this task done with beginners like me. this is the screenshots that shows the answer posted by **@edsappfactory.com** that worked for me:

**First** open the Gradle view on the right side of Androidstudio, in your app's item go to `Tasks` then `Android` then right-click `androidDependencies` then choose `Run`:

[image: step 1]

**Second** you will see something like this :

[image: Step 2]

The main reason i posted this that it was not easy to know where to execute a `gradle` task or the commands posted above. So this is where to excute them as well.

SO, to execute gradle command:

First:

[image: first]

Second:

[image: second]

Easy as it is.

Thats it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33):

Also to note you can see your android dependencies, by going to your Android Studio Gradle view, and selecting the target "androidDependencies".

One more tip: I was having this issue, until I removed the v4 support lib from the libs folder in both the project and my related module/library project(s).

Comment: More specific instruction? Can't find "androidDependencies". Thx

Comment: Go to the Gradle view, then find the heading All tasks, drill down on your app's name, then drill down on ":app", you will find "androidDependencies" there.

Comment: Where is the Gradle view?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien If you look to the far right side of the window, there's a sideways tab marked Gradle. Click it to open a pinned view. The androidDependencies is actually a gradle task

Comment: thank you man, i posted screenshots explaining your answer to make it easier.

Answer (score 11):

I started getting this error when upgrading to ButterKnife 8.5.1.  None of the other answers here worked for me.

I used `gradle -q :app:dependencies` to see the tree, and then looked through jar files until I found the conflict.  The conflict was that butterknife's dependency on `com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0` contains a version of the accessibility class, and `com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1` also contains the class.

I solved it by changing my dependency from this:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

to this:

```
compile('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-compat'
}
```

It doesn't seem to affect ButterKnife's operation so far.

Edit:  There is a better solution, which was to upgrade my android support libraries to match ButterKnife's:

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0')
compile('com.android.support:design:25.2.0')
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

Comment: keep the support version to be same is simple solution and exclude module is not work for me.

Comment: I solved with the second solution as well! Same conflict but with Butter Knife version 8.8.1

Example:

implementation ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
}
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

Answer (score 9):

In  case anyone finds out that the answer from [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/4068957) could not be applied to android library project, here is the snippet to fix

compile **(project(':yourAndroidLibrary'))**{
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
    }

You will find problems

> Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'exclude()'

if you use 
compile **project(':yourAndroidLibrary')**{
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
    }

The differences are the bracelet **"("** and **")"** before **"project"**.

Comment: Thanks, was missing double parenthesis!

Answer (score 8):

```
exclude module: 'support-v4'
```

Would not work for me with a project dependency, the only way I could get it to work was via the following syntax:

```
configurations {
    dependencies {
        compile(project(':Android-SDK')) {
            compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
    }
}
```

Where :Android-SDK is your project name.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it seems that my app had too many methods because of the libraries: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Solved it with:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
   ...
   multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}
```

More here [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > comcommand finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747363/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-comcommand-finished-with-non/32110091#32110091?newreg=6e065dfdd5764de28feac6fa0a8994c7)

Comment: Multidexing can make your app start up speed slower, only use it if you really have to.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same error but it was because I had recently changed from using v4 to v13.  So all I had to do was clean the project.

Comment: Had the same error after upgrading intellij, cleaning the project fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error on a legacy project. My fault was that the support-library was included twice: Once inside google-play-services lib, and another as standalone.

This is how I fixed it:

BAD build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
   compile files('libs/core-2.2.jar')
   compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar')
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
}
```

GOOD build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   // compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')  // not needed 
   compile files('libs/core-2.2.jar')
   compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar')
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
}
```

Hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0` and
`android-support-v13.jar` and could not get `exclude module: 'support-v4'` to work.

What worked for me was using the `android-support-v13` artefact rather than the `android-support-v13.jar` file.

I.e. instead of

```
dependencies {
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

}

I used

```
dependencies {
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0')
compile ('com.google.android:android-support-v13')
```

}

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was caused by **version inconsistency**:

```
Build tools 25
compileSdk 24
targetSdk 24
Support library 24
```

**The solution was simple: Make everything version 25**

Answer (score 3):

A **similar** dex issue resolved method

**gradle.build was containing:**

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

**The issue was resolved when i removed**

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
```

***My gradle now looks like:***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mmm.ll"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

There was a **redundancy** in the JAR file and the compiled gradle project

So keenly look for dependency and jar files having same classes.

And remove redundancy.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, go to your build.gradle (check both project and modules build.gradle files) and search for duplicate dependencies.

Delete those your project does not need.

Answer (score 2):

If you have imported your project from **Eclipse**.

```
1. The select project 
2. Go to File -> **Project Structure**
3. Select app in **module** section on left hand panel
4. Select **Dependency** tab
5. Your able to see jars you have added in eclipse project for v4 and v13.
6. Remove that jar by clicking on minus sign at bottom after selection
7. Click on Plus sign select **Library Dependency** 
8. Choose V4 and V13 if added
9. Press Ok and Clean and Rebuild your project
```

The scenario I have faced after importing Eclipse project to Android studio.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

**Deleting all files from Gradle cache fixed my problem.**

on Linux:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an annoying problem, that can take some time to find out the root case. The way you should proceed is @CommonsWare answer.

I faced this problem recently and found it hard to resolve.

**My problem was i was including a library by "+" version in build.gradle. Latest version of library contained one of older dex and bang.**

I reverted to older version of library and solved it.

It is good to run your androidDependencies and see what is really happening. Its also good to search in your build folder.

Above all **Android Studio 2.2** provide in build features to track this problem.

Happy Coding Guys

Answer (score 1):

I removed 
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
in dependencies, and it works

Comment: this should be a comment or else you should explain it in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem in my react native project by simply adding

```
configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-ui'
    }
```

at the end of my android\app\build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it modifiying these attributes on the module gradle file

1. compileSdkVersion 25
2. targetSdkVersion 25
3. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
4. compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when adding `react-native-palette` to my project, here is my dependencies tree:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
+--- project :react-native-palette
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.+ -> 0.44.2
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1 -> 24.2.1
...
|    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:24.+ -> 24.2.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1
|              \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)
\--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.44.2 (*)
```

I tried many solutons and could not fix it, until changing the `com.android.support:appcompat` version in `android/app/build.gradle`, I wish this can help:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-palette')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

it seems that multiple entries is not a big problem, version mismatch is

Answer (score 0):

Got it working for a `compile file('...')` conflict by increasing minSdkVersion to 21 and enabling multidex.  Not sure if that is the best solution but the only way I could get it working in my case.

Note: for `compile file('...')` it appears that you cannot put in an `exclude` clause so that option was not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution is changing the support version '27.+'(27.1.0) to '27.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.
In my project, I had the following dependencies :

- appcompat-v7
- android-support-v13

For legacy reasons, the appcompat was fetched from the Google Maven repo, whereas the android-support was a local .jar.

When I figured out this, and replaced this local reference with a maven reference, it just solved my build issue.

Here's the diff of my app/build.gradle :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved all of my issues by adding this into project.properties

```
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Received the following error**

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/constraint/ConstraintSet$1

**Fix : go to Build -> Clean Project**

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow. But please do not repeat answers, apart from already having 24 answers, building clean was already provided as an answer by ashishduh. Thanks!