# Unable to see dependency tree with gradlew OR gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running the latest release of gradle (1.12). In the project's root directory, I run the following command, which as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/588758) by @CommonsWare should give the dependency tree:

When I run it, this happens:

**$ gradle -q dependencies**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations
```

The project in question is an Android gradle project created from scratch using the new project wizard built in with Android Studio. My top-level build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "$rootDir/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

And my settings.gradle file looks like this:

```
include ':app', ':facebook', 'pullToRefresh'
```

From what I understand this is a very basic gradle configuration. Does anyone have an idea why the dependency tree function is returning nothing? Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: You're running that command from the project root directory, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. I should add that I tried running with ./gradlew as well and got the same result.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Your top level build.gradle doesn't have any dependencies itself. You'll have to run (from the project root dir):

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out how to get a dependency tree for a while now. The key is (as you said) to be in the right directory with the module specific build.gradle.

Comment: Question is quite old, but it didn't helped me. This task fails for every module in my project with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
'. Even if invoke task for another module (plain java). It always tries to resolve 'app' dependencies.

Comment: if i do ./ doesn't work without it works (running command from the project root). What could be the reason?

Comment: probably means you aren't on a linux based system - where the `./` is needed to specify a file in the current directory.

Comment: Anyway to just show the dependencies of my release? There's a lot here including test etc...