# Multiple dex files define android/support/annotation/AnimRes

Tags: android, gradle, dex

When I`m tring to run my app, I receive the following error:

app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

The content of the gradle script is:

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 289
        versionName "2.2.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':UtilsLibrary')
    compile project(':NumberPickerLibrary')
    compile project(':drag-sort-listview-lib')
    compile project(':GoogleAPI Library')
    compile project(':MenuDrawerLibrary')
    compile project(':IOLibrary')
    compile project(':AR Library')
    compile project(':GoogleLicense')
    compile project(':android-maps-utils-library')
}
```

I`m sure that somehow I added twice an of the google libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the other modules, which are compiled for this module.

The best way to see what is contained as dependencies is to use [gradlew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398041/build-android-studio-app-via-command-line).

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026378/unable-to-see-dependency-tree-with-gradlew-or-gradle) how to generate the dependencie three.

now you have to look with the three where the other google librarie is.