# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webrtc/AudioSource.class

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-android

I am using webrtc module in my application. In iOS its working fine but when coming to android its showing the following error

[image]

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.roger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
           exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so"

        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile project(':react-native-voximplant')
    compile project(':react-native-android-permissions')

    compile project(':react-native-simpledialog-android')
    compile project(':WebRTCModule')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-network-info')
    compile project(':react-native-error-reporter')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':@remobile/react-native-splashscreen')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-barcodescanner')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0') {
        force = true;   

}   
    compile project(':react-native-webview-bridge')
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Comment: Hey, use this command http://stackoverflow.com/a/24027035/2125612 and see if there is duplicate entry for 'WebRTCModule' module.

Comment: Go inside 'android' directory and execute the above command

Comment: @Jickson how to fix if there are 2 library using 'WebRTCModule'?