# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, dex

I'm using Android Studio for the first time and I got the following error after importing the project (previously it was an eclipse project where I had issues too.)

Here is the information given:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The app build.gradle is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.4.jar')
}
```

And the project built.gradle is this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be and how can it be solved? A good explanation for the problem would be useful too as I am new to Android Studio. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

I think you should remove 1 of those lines.

Comment: This fixed this problem, thank you, but now I have this: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
   File 1: /home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
   File 2: /home/crash-id/AndroidstudioProjects/LocalSin/app/libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar

Comment: Never mind. Fixed it by adding exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' to packagingOptions {..}

Answer (score 13):

cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android

Comment: Please add an explaination for your intention or put this text as a comment.

Comment: I'm up-voting because it works, but I agree a little explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. If you're using React Native and you're running into this or `Execution failed for task ':app:dexProductionDebug'` then this will most likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' that i solve it by setting multiDexEnabled to true

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Too many library were used in my project so i exceed the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android for more information see : http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 3):

> This happens because you are duplicating the library dependency inside of app build.gradle in android studio.

Android Studio automatically adds the dependencies for all the files in the libs folder by using

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

or in your specific case the dependency is added using

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

---

**^** Now when you try to add the dependency again by using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you get the error.

---

---

**SOLUTION**

Remove all duplicate dependencies added inside the "app build.gradle" and you should be good to go.In your case remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ensure that the Package names are not duplicated across the projects being compiled

In [@Drivers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787876/3063884), it is pointed out that in a given project, there should not be multiple dependencies that have the same namespace. In the case above, the *Google Play Services* library had been included twice, and thus caused a package name conflict.

The same can also happen across multiple modules (apps, libraries etc.) in the same project. So, ensure that for each `AndroidManifest.xml` file, the `package` name is unique across all modules:-

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="this.must.be.unique.across.modules">
```

Answer (score 2):

avoid to include whole gms library:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

Instead, just use required components in this way:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the below code on gradle file and same error.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```

Removed those last 3 dependencies and now its working!

Answer (score -2):

delete all files in `c:\users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\`

Enjoy the command `flutter run`