# How to fix this gradle app:dexDebug error?

Tags: android, build.gradle

im using android studio,now in my app i have this error when i run my app

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run     command:
/home/noob/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/noob/Desktop/NavigationDrawer/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug  --input-   list=/home/noob/Desktop/NavigationDrawer/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debu    g/inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

and this is my gradle.build file :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.navigationdrawer"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
}
```

so how can i fix this problem, because i dont recive error in my code,and my app is very simple !and i think my error is in the gradle file

Comment: Check out this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different version of the same library.

In your case, `appcompat` and `support-v13` have the same dependency: `support-v4`.

You have to use the same version of `support-v4`.

I suggest you to change your dependency in:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
}
```

and remove the `android-support-v13.jar` from the libs folder.