# How to fix this gradle app:dexDebug error while importing twitter SDK?

Tags: android, twitter, android-gradle-plugin

Referring question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429546/how-to-fix-this-gradle-appdexdebug-error).
Problem is that i am including something which is repeated.
Can somebody help me figure which one is causing problem?

And this error started arising when i added twitter sdk.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sony.login_signup"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.8'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
gradle -q dependencies
```

It should output a tree of all gradle dependencies and their dependencies. If you trace the dependency tree you will find which ones are using support-v4 and their versions, to tell you where the problem is.

EDIT:

This should be run on a command line / terminal. Gradle is just another program...

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html

To do this, make sure that "gradle" is in your environment PATH (this is different depending on if you're Windows or Mac, but if you search you will find it).

Then run the command from the folder where your "build.gradle" and "settings.gradle" files are located (your project "root" folder typically).

Comment: thanks for that answer but i am noob on this, can you tell me where to put that code? and when i find the problem, do i have to remove one of the library or can i just remove a dependency.