# How I solve processException ?

Tags: android

Before i ask question , i try search google 
but I can not find a satisfactory answer.

build error message is

> Execution failed for tas ':app:dexDebug'.>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.proceess.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:￦Program Files￦Java￦jdk1.8.0_60￦bin￦java.exe'' finished with non_zero exit value 2

build.gradle(Module: app)

```
dependencies {
// 记得添加nineoldandroids
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'cn.bingoogolapple:bga-refreshlayout:1.1.3'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-cardview.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-palette.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar') }
```

if you need more information. reply for me 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429546/how-to-fix-this-gradle-appdexdebug-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line in your app Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and then below line in defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: thanks, but Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebuglassesForMultiDex'. >java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/AsyncListUtil$2.class   build message                           thank once again

Comment: then add few more things for that check my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551732/android-multidexenable-true-causes-picasso-to-crash/35552476#comment58795836_35552476