# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs

Tags: android, gradle

Been banging my head on this for hours now. What could be the problem with my dependencies? I keep getting the error `com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;`

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
compile ('de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7')
compile ('org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE')
compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3')
compile ('uk.co.icatalyst:android-support-v4:18')
compile ('org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2')
compile ('org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1')
compile ('com.splunk.mint:mint:4.1')
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility

Comment: Use gradle -q dependencies to check which library is duplicated

Comment: Thanks - found the culprit. uk.co.icatalyst:android-support-v4:18 was loading a duplicated android support 4