# Error resolving dependencies with Gradle, in Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have configured the following dependencies in Gradle, inside Android Studio.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-storage-0.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-cli-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/rabbitmq-client.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-1.7.1.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

But Gradle gives me the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\AS sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\ttuser\ASProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\ttuser\ASProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Answer (score 1):

**`app:dexDebug`**  `error in general means that you've tried to link in the duplicate class to your project more than once`. So remove your **Duplicate Library**

Comment: I know, but I can't find the deplicate library

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you figured it out yet, but seeing as all of those are publicly available libraries, I suggest getting rid of the JARs and getting them as a dependency from JCenter/Maven Central. If you are not sure how to do this, here is an example. One library you are using is Retrofit, so you would go to a website like Maven Central (http://search.maven.org/) and search for the library and get the Gradle dependency for your version (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.squareup.retrofit|retrofit|1.7.1|jar):

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
```

Do this for all of your dependencies. Once you have them set up as Gradle dependencies instead of JARs, you can do what is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/2245921

Basically, go into your :app folder through a terminal, and run the following:

```
../gradlew -q dependencies
```

And Gradle will draw a dependency tree. There you will be able to see duplicate dependencies and more easily deal with them.