# Androidstudio: finished with non-zero exit value2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been learning how to use hidden API these days, and I know how to use classes.jar.
I put this classes.jar in the app module as a library.

When I run this application, I get

> "Error:Execution failed for task
>       ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>       org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>       'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>       non-zero exit value 2"

I really hope somebody can help me.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.wifidisplay"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('classes-dex2jar.jar')
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file also

Comment: Go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility/21100040#21100040) .

Answer (score 1):

this question answered in this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028505

this answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by choosing the option " Build > Clean Project " in Android studio.