# Android gradle modules with the same name

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am working on an Android project that uses the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

However this dependency has 2 definitions of the module javax/inject as shown here in the gradle dependency tree:

```
 +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.17
 |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.17
 |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.4.0-b10
 |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
 |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.4.0-b10
```

When attempting to run the Android application I get the error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define L/javax/inject/Inject
```

I have tried excluding either of these modules but that does not work because the dependency relies on both of them to make method calls.

Are there any other solutions to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Maybe this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility

Answer (score 10):

I am using gradle and had the same issue and solved it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040) answer

```
compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'){
    exclude module: 'javax.inject'
}
compile 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.4.0-b06'
```

Comment: I have this : `implementation('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1') {
        exclude module: 'javax.inject'
    }

    implementation 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.4.0-b06'`
But it doesn't work.  
Says UnexpectedInput.