# Android linphone.jar Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, linphone, android-multidex

After adding [linphone android sdk](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads) I encountered this problem:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

I know that problem is in android `support-v4` because linphone uses this. But I have no idea how to exclude it from `*.jar` file.
Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1')
}
```

`linphone.jar` located in lib folder.

I read this answer:
[Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

But it didn't help me.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Would you mind to share a test project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])