# Multiple libraries are using the same jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

Using eclipse IDE, I have 2 different libraries added to my project, but now the problem is that:

```
library A uses nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar
library B uses nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar
```

and when I run my project I get the following error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener
```

How is it possible to fix this error??

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray

Comment: include nineoldandroid in main project and remove ref from library project

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain that makes the library project shoots errors everywhere since it needs those jars

Comment: try to exclude from build types from one lib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24025291/3664628