# Android - Multiple dex files defined when importing a jar file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import caldav4j library (caldav4j-0.7.jar) into my android studio project. I have the following two lines in my build.gradle file.

```
compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
compile files('libs/caldav4j-0.7.jar')
```

I am seeing **multiple dex files defined error** due to ical4j library because caldav4j-0.7.jar also has ical4j library defined as a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.fortuna.ical4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
  <!--version>1.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT</version--><!-- patched on localhost-->
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If I try to not to import ical4j separately by removing the first line,

```
compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
```

then I don't have access to ical4j package at all.. What I want to achieve is being able to import any classes from ical4j package. Is it normal for a maven project to not expose its dependencies' packages? Then how am I supposed to use **ical4j** inside my project? All import statements for ical4j library fails if I remove that line from build.gradle.

```
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Component;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ComponentList;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.VEvent;
```

**In short:**

I want to import **ical4j** library but,

1. It gives me **multiple dex files defined error** if I separately add a line to build.gradle because of the conflicts with the internal dependency defined in caldav4j.jar.
2. If I remove that line, I don't have access to ical4j library at all because caldav4j.jar does not expose its dependencies..

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

It should be a comment, because I am not sure about it, but it is too long. I will remove it if it is wrong.

First of all, you should be able to import the `caldav4j` library using a gradle dependency.

Add the `caldav4j` repo to your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://caldav4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven" }    
}
```

Then you can use

```
compile('org.osaf:caldav4j:0.7') {
        exclude group: 'net.fortuna.ical4j', module: 'ical4j'
    }
```

However I am not sure that it can work because I don't know if 1.0.6 is full compatible with 1.0 in the pom [file](http://caldav4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/org/osaf/caldav4j/0.7/caldav4j-0.7.pom):

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.fortuna.ical4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
      <!--version>1.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT</version--><!-- patched on localhost-->
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I already tried this but have encountered a different error which says:
 trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
  Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
  when not building a core library.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer, it pretty much tells you how to list out what's conflicting,

[Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Run gradle -q dependencies (or gradle -q :projectName:dependencies) to generate a dependency report. You should see where r7 is coming from, such as:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4
|    +--- com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android:support-v4:r7
|    +--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.5.4
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
```

Then, use the exclude directive to block that dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

(where the second compile statement indicates what version you actually want)