# Cordova com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics with com.admob.google

Tags: android, cordova

I use Apache Cordova 4 to build my Android project with two Cordova plugins added:
com.admob.google 4.0.7
and
com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics

when I execute

```
$cordova build
```

I get the following error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple
>   dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
>   at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170) at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188) at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287) at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230) at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199) at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
>
> :dexDebug FAILED

I found out that this is a problem with multiple dependency, but can I solve this in anyway? When I remove one of the plugins build works ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this in another way:

1. I extracted platforms/android/com.google.play.services/[App Name]-google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar
2. I removed conflicting classes
3. I used CLI jar to recreate the jar again
4. I replaced google-play-services.jar with the new version

Comment: how do you know the names of conflicting classes?

Comment: You can also simply open the jar with WinRAR and delete de classes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Multiple Dex problem with the Facebook plugin and  com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics

I was able to solve the problem by creating a custom rule in danielcwilson's plugin.xml:

In order to have your changes take effect, you have to add and remove the analytics plugin, which will stomp over any local changes you make. To prevent that, pull from the source and make the changes below or use my fork of the branch:

My fork:
https://github.com/diego-link-eggy/google-analytics-plugin

Solution:
In plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics I created a pixme-play-services-analytics-exclude-v4.gradle file which contains:

```
dependencies {
   compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+') {       
       exclude module: 'support-v4'
   }
}
```

In the plugin.xml comment out the old framework reference and replace it with the gradle rule you just created:

```
 <platform name="android">
      <!-- <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+" /> -->
      <framework src="play-services-analytics-exclude-v4.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

Then remove and add the analytics plugin to have the change take effect.

```
  cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-google-analytics
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/diego-link-eggy/google-analytics-plugin
     OR
   cordova plugin add <path to where you cloned source>
```

This answer came from reading the solution posted here:
[Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

and the Cordova plugin spec found here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification

Comment: This doesn't work on cordova android 4.1.1 anymore, do you have any idea why?

Comment: I upgraded and then  added and removed fb plugin and analytics  plugin. I had no problems.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I did that, gradle build was updated but it didn't work. But i solved my problem with creating build-extras.gradle and adding: configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
But i didn't use your fork with this. This fixes the problem with fb and any other plugin that uses support lib.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of `com.admob.google` (which now has been moved to `cordova-admob` and is the one that will be mantained)

You can also use this analytics plugin which has no conflict with `cordova-admob`: https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-analytics
```

And if you would like to use adId: https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google-adid

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-analytics-adid
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened because I updated my whole project and had the cordova-plugin-googleplayservices installed from previous versions.

Removing the plugin fixed my issue (make sure it does not reinstall on build as I had that issue several times until I realized):

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googleplayservices
```