# Where to run gradle commands

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/609782),

> Run gradle -q dependencies (or gradle -q :projectName:dependencies) to
>   generate a dependency report. You should see where r7 is coming from,
>   such as:
>   which will produce result like - 
>   compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.

```
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4
|    +--- com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android:support-v4:r7
|    +--- com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.5.4
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+ -> 18.0.0
```

My question is, where to run these `gradle` commands, I tried running `gradlew.bat` from my project root, I have no clue, is it some 'gradle command prompt'?

**EDIT**

[image: Commmand prompt screenshot], 
though running it in `terminal` of android studio downloaded the `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip and configured it's`path` automatically, and the command worked.

PS - post a comment as why 'downvoted', it helps OP to improve their quality of posts.
`

Comment: `gradlew -q dependencies` from Windows command line or Linux terminal. That's it.

Comment: if you use android studio you can run the commands from the terminal

Comment: I guess I am missing 'setting the path to gradle' or something, that's why it is showing 'gradlew is not recognized as internal or external command'.

Comment: `./gradlew` to run it from the current dir.

Comment: It downloaded the gradle's zip while I ran it from command prompt. Thanks @Raghunandan

Comment: @Darpan you are welcome.