# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/HttpConnection with Gradle and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Development environment**:

- OS: Windows 7
- JDK: 1.8.0_66
- Android Studio: 1.5, built Nov. 12 2015
- Gradle: v2.8

**build.gradle**

[image]

**`libs` folder**

[image]

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Exception**

`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/HttpConnection;`

Stuck with this issue for the past two days. Understood that there are multiple definitions of that class in the dependencies, but clueless on the fix. Was unable to get any of the answers on this topic to work.

On `Eclipse` this project / module runs without any issues. This is my first shot at Gradle on Android Studio. So,:

Is there a specific Android-Gradle plugin (or similar) that needs to be installed?

Adding `dexOptions { preDexLibraries = false }` also fails: 
`Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'dexOptions()' Possible causes: The project 'XXX' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.`

Any glaring error in the way things are setup here?

Comment: Try add: `dexOptions { preDexLibraries = false}` to gradle file of your project

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/5038873) answer.

Comment: @mdtuyen, thanks for the response. Already tried that, Gradle comes back with `Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'dexOptions()' Possible causes: The project 'XXX' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.`

Comment: what is in your libs folder ?

Comment: @mdtuyen, Have already posted the image of the libs folder in the question, please review. Unable to post that image in this comment.

Comment: Check out whcih of your libs reference to HttpConnection. Either check your build folder or use the gradle command of my link. Then delete a lib of exclude this in your gradle file.

Comment: @oberflansch, Thanks. 

* Had already tried the `-q dependencies` command line earlier, `HttpConnection` does not figure anywhere in the dependencies trees. 
* Looked in the root `build` folder: the `dependency-cache\debug` folder is empty