# Android - App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android

Getting the following error when I build my Android project.

Any help is much appreciated.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeDataDroid')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeFacebookSDK')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeSmoothProgressBar')
    //compile project(':Modules:InstaRyde_google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':googlemapssdkm4b_lib')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.5'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.2"

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0"){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0"){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0"){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: post your build gradle file

Comment: need another build gradle(Module:app)

Comment: you post build gradle(project)  but need build gradle(Module:app)

Comment: @sasikumar Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility