# android gradle Multiple dex files define in .jar class

Tags: android, gradle, jar, ionic-framework

I use Ionic Framework to build a android app.
I have created a custom plugin with my jars

dd-plist.jar
easylink_ftc_out.jar
jetty-8.1.15.jar

in libs folder

and my gradle code:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

when I run 'ionic run android' command.
show:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/component/LifeCycle;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)

And LifeCycle Class is in my jetty-8.1.15.jar

Run gradle -q dependencies

```
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.1.201405082137
 +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137
 |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
 +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.1.201405082137
 |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137 (*)
 |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
 \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137
```

How can I fix this ??

Comment: It means that you are adding twice the same class

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti You are right. But I don't know how to set build.gradle file to avoid it. Can you help me ?

Comment: It depends. Only in a maven dependency you can avoid it.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti not other easy way to fix it ..??? like 'exclude ' [usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility).

Comment: exclude can't work with a jar file.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have uploaded jars to jcenter.
And in build.gradle
`compile 'com.vanward.smart:gradle-aar-example:1.2'`
But still not work it out