# Unexpected top level exception in android

Tags: android

Hello everyone i have gone through all the ans in stackoverflow but still my problem in unsolved.
        here is my gradle file(app).There is no complile time error but when i run the project the error comes.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.android.animationsdemo"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    }
```

Error:-

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
            at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: you have added one library two times

Comment: i cann't see them.where are they in my code.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full gradle file you are posting ? Or you removed something to optimize question.

Comment: remove the fileTree line ie compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **defaultConfig** with this or just add  `multiDexEnabled true` in your **defaultConfig**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.animationsdemo'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled = true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable multidex in your build gradle. It should be inside the build gradle having the package name, version name, code etc and not on the outer .gradle file.

Add

multiDexEnabled = true

inside defaultConfig