# Add gradle dependency to support android.util.ArrayMap

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I have a sample project that has a gradle dependency to support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

When I run program this sometimes this exception occures:

```
Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
```

I searched and find out I should add this dependency to gradle:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:23.3.0"
```

or
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"

So I added dependency to gradle, but this time when I try to run app I get this error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

What should I do?

Comment: `When I run program this sometimes this exception occures` And it crashes your app?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/5245903

Comment: I can't say it's a exception that causes to crash app. not responding app dialog does not appear and my app restarts automatically

Answer (score 1):

`android.util.ArrayMap` is not from a library. That is part of the Android firmware, but only on API Level 19+ devices.

So, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 19, and you want to use the library implementation, switch to `android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap`.

Comment: `referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher` I feel like OP doesn't use it directly, it's just system that logs that.