# How to handle differences in minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion between app module and third party modules?

Tags: android

I have an Android app that has several third-party modules included in the project. I noticed that each third-party module has a different minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion than the other modules and my app module.

If a third party module has a minSdkVersion of 15 and my app module has a minSdkVersion of 16 then I assume there will be no conflicts due to the minSdkVersion because my app module guarantees that the app will only be installed on devices with API 16+. Is this assumption correct?

If a third party module has a minSdkVersion of 16 and my app module has a minSdkVersion of 15 will there be an error at compile time? Or do I just need to perform version checks in my app module's source before calling any code from the third party module?

If a third party module has a different compileSdkVersion than my app module is that an issue? Do they need to be the same? Is it good practice to make them the same?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027019/how-to-manage-different-support-library-versions-for-3rd-party-deps-with-gradle