# Runtime error relatives from library ,please tell me the solution

Tags: android

Please tell me what is the reason of this Exception

*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex*

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: Read [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027019/how-to-manage-different-support-library-versions-for-3rd-party-deps-with-gradle). The problem is libraries and your project are using different versions of support libraries .

Answer (score 0):

add this to defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and in dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In Android tag

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: still not working..after add these two things which add in comment then showing this error in below

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\irfan data\LiveSelfie2\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\work\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\6c349993f8e00cdcfe9926756c17c684\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

Comment: try to add this in 
android {
-------
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
------}

Comment: mean i have to add this in which place????                                                                                         
          dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }

Comment: after closing defaultConfig brace paste that code check answer

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true

Comment: applicationId "com.logiclump.technologies.liveselfie"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
            dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: still same error after add your code see my all code

Comment: In my case helped an update of libraries defined inside app gradle file to newest versions: `'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` and `'compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`