# android support libraries must use exact same version?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to import the following library:

```
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
```

but I get the following error when I sync:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-rc01, 27.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01 and
>   com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0...

I tried adding the following but nothing has helped. How do I fix this?

```
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface-28.0.0-rc01'
```

Comment: "I tried adding the following but nothing has helped" -- you should be getting a different error message, one no longer referring to `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0`. Check the new error message and see what it is complaining about. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066485/115145

Comment: Please show your gradle file.

Comment: I get the following: "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:exifinterface-28.0.0-rc01:" Am I trying to import the wrong version number?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have `compileSdkVersion 28` and  `targetSdkVersion 28` in android block in **build.gradle** file.

also make sure you have `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01` in your dependencies block.

Then i think `implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc01'` can be added without any problem.

I am pasting my **build.gradle (Module:app)** for reference.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chirag.example.retrofeitdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```