# Gradle error: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex

When I added a new implementation to my gradle file (`implementation "com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:2.0.0-RC10"`) I got the following error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/StateListAnimator;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/StateListAnimator;
```

I tried to exclude the support library by changing the implementation to this but no success:

```
implementation ("com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:2.0.0-RC10") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Is there a way to exclude the support library on this implementation so I won't get the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/4168607 may  help .

Comment: @ADM tried to do that, got an gradle error, updated gradle to 4.6 and that fixed my original error.. Thanks!