# App running smoothly but failed in build peekaboo integration?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-multidex

I integrated peekaboo in my cordova app when I run my mobile application its running fine and every functionality is working but when I start build source code in android studio then it gives following error.

```
Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lokhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketReader$FrameCallback;
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lokhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketReader$FrameCallback;, sources=[Unknown source 
file], original message=UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lokhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketReader$FrameCallback;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:660)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:615)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:597)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:197)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:503)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:333)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:288)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:244)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
, tool name=Optional.of(Dex)}
```

can anyone guide me regarding issue where I am doing mistake actually before my application was working perfectly when I integrate peekaboo then it is giving this error on build.and here is my project build.gradle file.

```
/*
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
   */

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
   // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
   // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version- 
   compatibility
  // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    jcenter()
}
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.3'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build- 
extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: 
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
 apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
// The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
}
// The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
}
// Sets the versionCode to the given value.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
    cdvVersionCode = null
}
// Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
    cdvMinSdkVersion = null
}
// Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
    cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
}
// .properties files to use for release signing.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
    cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
}
// .properties files to use for debug signing.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
    cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
}
// Set by build.js script.
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
    cdvBuildArch = null
}

// Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "peekaboo/allied-peekaboo.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

 def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
 if (hasBuildExtras) {
  apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
 }

 // Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
 if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
  ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
 }
 if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
  ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
 }
 if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug- 
 signing.properties').exists()) {
  ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
 }
 if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release- 
 signing.properties').exists()) {
  ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
 }

 // Cast to appropriate types.
 ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : 
 cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
 ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' 
 + 
 cdvMinSdkVersion)
 ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + 
 cdvVersionCode)

 def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
 def ret = 'assemble'
 if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
    def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
    ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
 }
 return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
    println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + 
flavor.versionCode)
}
}

android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
     }
     }

defaultConfig {
    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + 
    privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }
}

lintOptions {
  abortOnError false;
}

compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
    productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", ""
            }
        }
        all {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "all", ""
            }
        }
    }
}
/*

ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
  def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: 
privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
  // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
  // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
  // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system 
webview.
  if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
  } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
  }
}
*/

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are 
            overridden).
            keyAlias = ""
            keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in 
           order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
            storeFile = null
            storePassword = "__unset"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
           'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
}
if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
    addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile project(path: 'CordovaLib', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: 'CordovaLib', configuration: 'release')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
    return;
}
if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = 
privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
}
if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = 
privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
}
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
    if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 
'validateSigningRelease') {
        promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
    }
}
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
def props = new Properties()
propsFile.withReader { reader ->
    props.load(reader)
}

def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: 
privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
    storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, 
storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
}
if (!storeFile.exists()) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + 
storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
}
signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: 
privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', 
props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', 
props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
if (!storeType) {
    def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
    if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
        storeType = 'pkcs12'
    } else {
        storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
    }
}
signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
postBuildExtras()
}
```

Comment: This is because that you have duplicate classes. See the discussion from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Comment: If you still cannot figure out your problem by looking into the links above, just submit your build.gradle files so that I can help further.

Comment: i have added build.gradle file in above question. @shizhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick research for the peekaboo lib you mentioned here, but cannot find any information that is publicly available, maybe this is your proprietary library.

But, from the error message, it is because you have more than one places including the classes from `okhttp3` library. If you want use the one from your peekaboo module, then you can remove this line in your dependencies closure.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
```

Or modify it as below to exclude the `okhttp` from `com.squarup`

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0' {
    exclude module: "okhttp"
}
```

And, you can always use below gradle command to anylise your dependency tree.

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

Try to find where your `okhttp` modules exist and exclude one of them so that you can escape from the error of Multiple dex files definition when do **Dex** merging.

Comment: can you please tell me where i execute ./gradlew -q dependencies command?

Comment: Your project root directory

Comment: @shizen thank u so much when i commentcompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'.this line then its working fine thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove .gradle folder and .idea folder from your project folder and than rebuild the project

Comment: Please don't post multiple answer hit and trials.

Comment: can i try this solution @VicJordan what u suggest?

Comment: No, this is also not the solution. The solution has been discussed in the link i provided in the comment columns of your original question.

Comment: i saw above link which u provided still same issue i am facing.

Comment: @AmmarMuhiUdDin, can post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @shizhen i have added build.gradle.