# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/os/ResultReceiver;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

After adding the project:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation project(':xrecyclerview')
}
```

I can't Make Project although I added:

```
defaultConfig {
...
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Error:

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/os/ResultReceiver;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily find which two library have same class `ResultReceiver`.

Comment: Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can you please share your solution @Hai Bui